# Mensajes informativos cuando el ratón está sobre un boton en JavaFX

Tags: javafx, interfaz-gráfica, javafx-css

Estoy creando una aplicación javafx y necesito que aparezca un mensaje cuando paso el ratón encima de un botón. Con que clase de la API de JavaFX puedo desarrollar este tipo de eventos?

Comment: ¿Conocés los _tooltips_? Ahí te di una pista ;)

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas la clase Tooltip

## Ejemplo

```
    Button button = new Button("Púlsame");
    button.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Dice que le pulses"));
```

También puedes cambiar el estilo del Tooltip. Tienes la documentación aquí:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tooltip